# how to get final redirected url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, feedparser

i am using google app engine for fetching the feed url bur few of the urls are 301 redirect i want to get the final url which returns me the result

i am usign the universal feed reader for parsing the url is there any way or any function which can give me the final url.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to get the 'final' URL by parsing, in order to resolve it, you would need to at least perform an HTTP HEAD operation

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [urlfetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/), you can just access the `final_url` attribute of the [response object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects.html) you get from `urlfetch.fetch()`, assuming you set `follow_redirects` to `True`:

```
>>> from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
>>> url_that_redirects = 'http://www.example.com/redirect/'
>>> resp = urlfetch.fetch(url=url_that_redirects, follow_redirects=False)
>>> resp.status_code
302 # or 301 or whatever
>>> resp = urlfetch.fetch(url=url_that_redirects, follow_redirects=True)
>>> resp.status_code
200
>>> resp.final_url
'http://www.example.com/final_url/'
```

Note that the `follow_redirects` keyword argument defaults to `True`, so you don't have to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by handling redirects manually. When calling fetch, pass in `follow_redirects=False`. If your response object's HTTP status is a redirect code, either 301 or 302, grab the `Location` response header and fetch again until the HTTP status is something else. Add a sanity check (perhaps 5 redirects max) to avoid redirect loops.